# Multilingual URLs in Sitemap.xml for SXA 1.5

Tags: sxa, multilingual, seo, sitemap

I am having a Sitecore SXA (1.5) instance site which has multiple language for each country. For example:

`www.mysite.be/fr-BE` (Country: Belgium, Lang: French)

`www.mysite.be/nl-BE` (Country: Belgium, Lang: Dutch)

But the `sitemap.xml` shows only urls which have the default language setup without any language id in the URL

Example here is my `sitemap.xml` output:

```
<url>
<loc>www.mysite.be/onze-producten</loc>
<lastmod>2018-12-12</lastmod>
<changefreq>Daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://www.mysite.be/over-merk</loc>
<lastmod>2018-12-12</lastmod>
<changefreq>Daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
<url>
<loc>https://www.mysite.be/contacteer-ons</loc>
<lastmod>2018-12-11</lastmod>
<changefreq>Daily</changefreq>
<priority>0.5</priority>
</url>
```

But it doesn't shows pages related to French language. For example:

```
www.mysite.be/fr-be/contactez-nous

www.mysite.be/fr-be/faq
```

If this is a custom implementation, please guide.

EDIT:

As per the answer below I tried making this to work, but no luck:

```
public class CustomSiteMap : SitemapGenerator
    {
        protected override StringBuilder BuildSitemap(IEnumerable<Item> childrenTree, SitemapLinkOptions options)
        {
            var items = LanguageSitemap.GetSitemapItems();// gets all items below Home node
            var xDocument = LanguageSitemap.Generate(items); // generates sitemap xml with hreflang and language specific urls
            return new StringBuilder(xDocument.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SXA supports multiple languages Sitemap from **SXA 1.6**- check the release notes [here](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Accelerator/16/Sitecore%20Experience%20Accelerator%2016%20Initial%20Release/Release%20Notes) for more details-

```
The SEO Sitemaps aggregate all the available sites under a single hostname, and support multiple languages  494598  9788
```

In your case you can customized the Sitemap XML generator for your SXA version, follow the below steps:

1) Create a new class that inherits from **SitemapGenerator**

2) Override **BuildSitemap**() method-  Here you can write your own code/business logic and generate the customized sitemap.xml to support multiple languages.

I hope this helps to give you a starting point.

Comment: Hi Ankit, I tried this, but its not working. It is still displaying the default Sitemap.xml which SXA generates. Even tried to debug my method, but its not hitting the breakpoint. Please check my updated question above.